# Arduino String.toInt() function wrongly converts to uint32_t

Tags: string, arduino, type-conversion, uint32-t

I have a webserver running on an ESP32-Wrover_E.
A user's session id is stored in cookie format.
This session ID is coming from `esp_random()` function which returns an `uint32_t` type integer. It is being set on log in. When a user goes to any page or reloads it, the http route will check the session ID from the cookie. Sometimes it is matching, other times not.

I have created a wokwi sketch to represent the problem.
`toInt()` function often times does not convert a `String` to `uint32_t` properly.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  String user_session = "2227761735"; // <-- This number comes from esp_random();
  uint32_t sessionID = user_session.toInt();
  Serial.printf("String session: %s, uint32_t session: %lu\n",user_session,sessionID);
}

void loop() {
  vTaskDelay(1);
}
```

Here is a link to wokwi where you can see it yourself: https://wokwi.com/projects/342242993672028755

Here is the `esp_random()` function documentation:
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/random.html

How can i convert a `String` to `uint32_t`?

**EDIT:**

If you run this code at wokwi you can see that there are errors in the conversion:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  String user_session = "2227761735";
  uint32_t sessionID = user_session.toInt();
  Serial.printf("String session: %s, uint32_t session: %lu\n", user_session, sessionID);
}


boolean isConvertSuccess(uint32_t originalInteger, uint32_t convertedInteger) {
  if ( originalInteger == convertedInteger ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

long lastTestMS = 0;
void testSessionStringToInt() {
  if ( millis() - lastTestMS >= 2000 ) {
    lastTestMS = millis();

    uint32_t newSessionID = esp_random();
    Serial.println("\n**********");
    Serial.printf("newSessionID: %lu\n", newSessionID);
    String sessionComingFromA_Cookie = String(newSessionID);
    Serial.printf("sessionComingFromA_Cookie: %s\n", sessionComingFromA_Cookie);
    uint32_t convertedIntFromCookieString = sessionComingFromA_Cookie.toInt();
    Serial.printf("convertedIntFromCookieString: %lu\n", convertedIntFromCookieString);

    Serial.printf(
      "Conversion was: %s\n",
      isConvertSuccess(newSessionID, convertedIntFromCookieString) ? "success" : "failed"
    );

    Serial.println("**********");
  }
}

void loop() {
  delay(10);
  testSessionStringToInt();
}
```

Comment: `String.toInt()` return a `long`, not `uint32_t`, print out `UINT32_MAX` and `LONG_MAX` to seee yourself. So the code should work if you change it to `long newSessionID = (long) esp_random();`, and `long convetedINtFromCookieString`.

Comment: Generally I won't use "String.toInt()` as it known to return 0 for anything that is not a valid number, so it return 0 for "0", "0000", or "", as well as "anything else".

Comment: I never use wokwi, but it is kind of surprising to see that it actually considers a String as "%s", if you compile it on ESP32, you will get an error, because "%s" is expecting a const char*, so you have to use String.c_str().

Comment: %s works on PIO too. No error. I have always used it. I will try with long, thanks. As for the 0 return, it will always start with a number.

Comment: It seems to work with long conversion. I will test it with my big sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hcheung i just had to convert the `uint32_t esp_random()` to `long` and use `long` everywhere. Here is a link to the corrected wokwi ( where every `uint32_t` became a `long`, including the `printf("%lu")` to `printf("%ld")` since its not an unsigned ): https://wokwi.com/projects/342242993672028755

**And here is the corrected code:**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  String user_session = "2227761735";
  long sessionID = (long)user_session.toInt();
  Serial.printf("String session: %s, uint32_t session: %ld\n", user_session, sessionID);
}


boolean isConvertSuccess(long originalInteger, long convertedInteger) {
  if ( originalInteger == convertedInteger ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

long lastTestMS = 0;
void testSessionStringToInt() {
  if ( millis() - lastTestMS >= 2000 ) {
    lastTestMS = millis();

    long newSessionID = (long)esp_random();
    Serial.println("\n**********");
    Serial.printf("newSessionID: %ld\n", newSessionID);
    String sessionComingFromA_Cookie = String(newSessionID);
    Serial.printf("sessionComingFromA_Cookie: %s\n", sessionComingFromA_Cookie);
    long convertedIntFromCookieString = sessionComingFromA_Cookie.toInt();
    Serial.printf("convertedIntFromCookieString: %ld\n", convertedIntFromCookieString);

    Serial.printf(
      "Conversion was: %s\n",
      isConvertSuccess(newSessionID, convertedIntFromCookieString) ? "success" : "failed"
    );

    Serial.println("**********");
  }
}

void loop() {
  delay(10);
  testSessionStringToInt();
}
```